# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () for runtime.js main.js and polyfills.js,

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, firefox

I have spent plenty of time to find the cause for this error:
[image]
Which is happening in chrome, and safari, browsers only but not in Firefox. This is happening after deployment and not in local. I am running **angular 13** in the front end and **spring boot** as a backend. I place angular build file under `resources/static/` folder of my **API** and build a `jar` out of it.

I would really want to know what would be the cause of this and what is the best approach I could use to avoid it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems issue with angular version, may be I missed some vital info or a bug. I finally got it working with older angular version(Angular 11). I spent hours and hours to fix dependency conflict and imports and finally there is `no more 403 issue in chrome and safari` while accessing main.js, pollyfill.js and runtime.js. Hopefully someone will come with a reasoning for this issue